# Extract performance as a macro in rapidminer

Tags: machine-learning, data-mining, rapidminer

I am using rapidminer doing classification , I want to extract performance as a macro and print the performance on output after measuring the performance ,

Is there any way to do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the current version of RapidMiner (5.2.8) it is not possible to extract performances as a macro, but RapidMiner 5.3 (to be release later this month) will feature a Performance to Data operator, which will transform performances to an example set. From the example set you can then extract the macros you need with the Extract Macro operator.